# SharePoint Drop Downs Multiple Levels?

Tags: folder, dropdown, subfolders

I am working on SharePoint 365 (2013).
I want to create drop downs on the main page where I can hover over a link and then keep hovering until I get to my desired subfolder.
I am able to have the following: MAIN LINK... X number of sub-folder links... Y number of sub-sub-folder links.
I am unable to create a sub-sub-sub-folder link.  Is the Y (sub-sub-folder level) the furthest I can go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this without coding , by installing the [FlyView for SharePoint and Office 365 Sites (v2.5.3)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/FlyView%20for%20SharePoint%20and%20Office%20365%20Sites?hl=en-US) extension in your browser.

It's a very nice extension that will be applied to all site structure once it's enabled in your browser.

**[Output]**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!  It appears our organization blocks extensions in general but I can talk to IT and see if they will make an exception.

Comment: Is there an Internet Explorer plug available?  The one above would apply to Chrome only, right?

Comment: Hi @ErinA , based on the official site of this extension , there is an extension for IE , but I think it will require additional installation , but for chrome, it's easy and free extension. you could read more at http://aurorabits.com/flyview-for-sharepoint/ please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification :)